# MYSQL installer for Windows 7 64 bit OS?

Tags: mysql

I went to http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/ and could not find any installer for windows 64 bit os. Is there only 32 bit installer. 
Please point me in right direction.Moreover both installer mentioned at above link states same version but have different size.

**Update:-**

As its written on MySQL Site

> MySQL Installer is 32 bit, but will install both 32 bit and 64 bit
>   binaries.

Will it automatically install  appropriate version(32 bit/64 bit) as per my current OS(as i do not see the separate  binaries files for 64 bit and 32 bit).i downloaded the first one from the above link as per anwers below and got only one installer file mysql-installer-community-5.6.12.0.msi.

Comment: Folks really i do not know why it got closed,as its related to development and anwering it can help me to understand my doubt

Comment: One will aways find people that agree with you (or vote with you), no matter how stupid your idea is.

Comment: It is amazing how confusing their download page still is!! Why is there a 64 bit version to download in the fist place??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From that very page:

> Note: MySQL Installer is 32 bit, but will install both 32 bit and 64 bit binaries.

The different sizes is because the smaller one is a web installer, which doesn't download the actual components unless you select them (which means that installer requiers you to be online when installing, since it has to get the data).

Comment: Michael it would be helpful if you can comment on my updated post

Answer (score 5):

Note: MySQL Installer is 32 bit, but will install both 32 bit and 64 bit binaries.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can comment on my updated post

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to download the 64x version here

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=413091

Answer (score 1):

you can down it from

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=413091

Begin Your Download - mysql-5.6.12-winx64.zip

Answer (score 0):

From the same page http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

It says:

> Note: MySQL Installer is 32 bit, but will install both 32 bit and 64
>   bit binaries.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can comment on my updated post